# Add an object to a property by a key(position of prop is unknown) Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

i have a object like this :

defObj :

```
{
 id: 101,
 email: 'jack@dev.com',
 personalInfo: {
        name: 'Jack',
        addresses: {
            firstAddress : {
                  line1: 'westwish st',
                  line2: 'washmasher',
                  city: 'wallas',
                  state: 'WX'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a object like this :

addObj :

```
secondAddress : {
 line1: "aStreet",
 city : "aCity",
 state : "aState"
}
```

and i want a function that works like that :

```
addObjectToProperty(defObj, propertyName, addObj);
```

Basically it takes defObj as a parameter(like the first object), searches in it for the property (like addresses) and add the obj to it(basically "like" an array, but it cant be an array in my case, it has to be an object.)

An usage example would be something like :

```
addObjectToProperty(defObj,"addresses",addObj);
```

The result would be something like this :

```
{
     id: 101,
     email: 'jack@dev.com',
     personalInfo: {
            name: 'Jack',
            addresses: {
                firstAddress : {
                      line1: 'westwish st',
                      line2: 'washmasher',
                      city: 'wallas',
                      state: 'WX'
                },secondAddress : {
                  line1: "aStreet",
                  city : "aCity",
                 state : "aState"
                 } 
            }
        }
    }
```

How would i achieve a function like that? I cant change the structure of the object(like placing arrays inside it) and im not allowed to use external libaries like underscore.js
Greetings!

Comment: The example you're giving for `addObj` is not valid syntax. Is `secondAddress: { ... }` meant to be `{ secondAddress: { ... }} ` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to recursively search your object for a property with the given name, and copy the contents of the other object into it. This function does that:

```
function addObjectToProperty(toObj, underName, addObj) {
    for (let name in toObj) {
        if (name === underName) {
            Object.assign(toObj[name], addObj);
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof toObj[name] === 'object') {
            let added = addObjectToProperty(toObj[name], underName, addObj);
            if (added) return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried it with your example (with the modification I mentioned in my comment) and it yielded the result you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by checking keys and values of the object. If not found iterate the nested objects.

```js
function addObjectToProperty(object, key, value) {
    return Object.entries(object).some(([k, v]) =>
        k === key
            ? Object.assign(v, value)
            : v && typeof v === 'object' && addObjectToProperty(v, key, value)
    );
}

var defObj = { id: 101, email: 'jack@dev.com', personalInfo: { name: 'Jack', addresses: { firstAddress: { line1: 'westwish st', line2: 'washmasher', city: 'wallas', state: 'WX' } } } },
    addObj = { secondAddress: { ine1: "aStreet", city: "aCity", state: "aState" } };

addObjectToProperty(defObj, "addresses", addObj);

console.log(defObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the `addObj` or if there is only one property then

```
function addObjectToProperty(target, prop, source)
{
   var key = Object.keys(source)[0];
   target.personalInfo[prop][key] = source[key];
}
addObjectToProperty(defObj,"addresses",addObj);
```

But if there are going to be multiple such then iterate the keys of `source`

```
function addObjectToProperty(target, prop, source)
{
   Object.keys(source).forEach( s => (target.personalInfo[prop][s] = source[s]) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A object syntax like

```
secondAddress : {
 line1: "aStreet",
 city : "aCity",
 state : "aState"
}
```

is wrong.

You need a recursion which will check for the keys and pass another parameter to name this new key

```js
var defObj = {
  id: 101,
  email: 'jack@dev.com',
  personalInfo: {
    name: 'Jack',
    addresses: {
      firstAddress: {
        line1: 'westwish st',
        line2: 'washmasher',
        city: 'wallas',
        state: 'WX'
      }
    }
  }
}
var secondAddress = {
  line1: "aStreet",
  city: "aCity",
  state: "aState"
}

function addObjectToProperty(originalObj, prop, newObj, addName) {
  //iterating object using for..in
  for (var keys in originalObj) {
    // checking if key name matches and if this is a object
    if (keys === prop && typeof originalObj[keys] === 'object') {
      // add new value
      originalObj[keys][addName] = newObj;
    } else if (typeof originalObj[keys] === 'object') {
     // else call the same function with  new value
     // here originalObj[keys] will change
      addObjectToProperty(originalObj[keys], prop, newObj, addName)
    }
  }
}
addObjectToProperty(defObj, 'addresses', secondAddress, 'secondAddress');
console.log(defObj)
```